# Proper results displaying only after reset, but it should work for backspace button

Tags: javascript, html

Results are displaying as below in our page.

[image]

I am searching results based on entering values in "search box". Proper results display once, we enter values in search box.

Here **no "result" will start from 6**, so there is no values displaying.

[image]

And once we remove values from search box [ with backspace button in keyboard] , **it should display "original results" as like image 1**.

But still it display the results of entered values [6] as like image 2.

[image]

Again it will display proper results only when we click on **"Reset"** button. But it should work for **"backspace"** button only.

**FORM**

```
<form>
    Search:

    <select id="f_value2">
        <option value="entity_id">Order Id</option>
    </select>


    <input type="text" onkeyup="doFilter()" value="" id="f_value1" >
    <input type="reset" value="Reset" onClick="window.location.reload()">
</form>
```

**SCRIPT**

```
function doFilter() {
    var filterInfo=[
        {
            fieldName : $('select[id=f_value2]').val(),
            logic : "startWith",
            value : Sigma.Util.getValue("f_value1")
        },
        {
            fieldName : Sigma.Util.getValue("f_fieldName12"),
            logic : "greatEqual",
            value : Sigma.Util.getValue("f_value12")
        }
    ]
    var grid=Sigma.$grid("myGrid");
    var rowNOs=grid.applyFilter(filterInfo);
}


var colsOption = [

    {id: 'entity_id' , header: "Order Id" , width :"70"},

];
```

Comment: create a fiddle and share the link

Comment: I assume you don't filter anything at first load, right? But when you clear the text filed, your filter has an empty string inside `value`. This could lead to problems.

Comment: @selvassn Thanks , here problem is we are fetching values with help of php code,  if posssile i will try to add fiddle soon......

Comment: @Glufu Thanks, i will try your idea.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to check the value of `f_value2` field and if its empty apply an empty filter.
Will have to do a similar check for `f_fieldName12` as well.

```
function doFilter() {
    var filterInfo=[];
    var orderIdVal= $('select[id=f_value2]').val();
    if(!( orderIdVal===undefined || orderIdVal ==="")){
        filterInfo.push({
            fieldName : "entity_id",
                logic : "startWith",
                value : Sigma.Util.getValue("f_value1")
        });


    }
    var grid=Sigma.$grid("myGrid");
    grid.applyFilter(filterInfo);
}
```

Comment: @user5348fh8y5 there was syntax error in the code, I have corrected it. There was an extra dot in this line `filterInfo.push.({.`

Comment: sorry, i also didt observed syntax error, please check link, now table is displaying, but  when you enter `15` in search box & remove `5` from `backspace` , it should display results, but its not happening now

Comment: @user5348fh8y5 the fieldName in the filterInfo object should refer to the column name in your grid rather than the actual html element. Updated the code

Comment: you are just fantastic, i cant believe its working this much early.....

Answer (score 0):

Check your field value if it is empty then reset your form...as follows

```
<form id="form-filter">
Search:

<select id="f_value2">
    <option value="entity_id">Order Id</option>
</select>


<input type="text" onblur="doFilter()" value="" id="f_value1" >
<input type="reset" value="Reset" onClick="window.location.reload()">
</form>
```

AND

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function doFilter() {
    var filterInfo=[
        {
            fieldName : $('select[id=f_value2]').val(),
            logic : "startWith",
            value : Sigma.Util.getValue("f_value1")
        },
        {
            fieldName : Sigma.Util.getValue("f_fieldName12"),
            logic : "greatEqual",
            value : Sigma.Util.getValue("f_value12")
        }
    ]
    var grid=Sigma.$grid("myGrid");
    var rowNOs=grid.applyFilter(filterInfo);

    var filter = document.getElementById('f_value1').value;
    if (filter == "") {
       var grid = Sigma.$grid("grid_demo_id");
       grid.refresh(rowData);
       Sigma.Grid.render(grid);
    }
}

</script>
```

Comment: @user5348fh8y5 are you setting options value from ajax?

Comment: sorry, i was doing some testing, now you can check this [link](http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/php/site6/hikmat.php) , i used your code......

Comment: i think you are using some plugin.

Comment: use `onblur()` event.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132058/discussion-between-user5348fh8y5-and-hikmat-sijapati).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can just do this ?

Checking for its value on every keyup inside your own function?

```
doFilter()
{
   if($("#f_value1").val() == "")
   {
       window.location.reload();
       return;
   }

   //... rest of the things
}
```

Comment: `window.location.reload();` every time page is reloaded on empty `#f_value1` value onkeyup.

Comment: The reset button is doing the same thing!! @HikmatSijapati

Comment: I dint quite get that

Comment: let me explain , pls visit : [link](http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/php/site6/jones.php) , 
you can see textfield after "order id" dropdown, please enter tet `15` there,
than you can see all results are not displaying, now remove `5` by `backspace` button , still you can see no results, but once you 
remove both `15` by `backspace` button , than you can see results....

Comment: Yes that is what you wanted right ? Or something else ?

Comment: sorry, yes i wanted same , but filtering should work if we remove `5`only, because once we remove `5` still `1` will be there in `search box` as results are available for `1` , it should display results, please let me know if you need more clarification.....

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132061/discussion-between-user5348fh8y5-and-jones-vinoth-joseph).